# Full banner width over the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a banner that uses an image as the background. The image's size is 670*303. Is there a way to stretch the banner(image) to full width of the screen.

Demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/xGQtF/2/

And also, there is extra color(background-color: #808000)

[image: color]

below the banner, how to remove it?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead, you may want to do an right align on the picture and use a repeating background on the left. Don't expect `background-size` to work in IE 6/7/8

Comment: Another more IE friendly way to do it is to use the `img` element with  100% `width`. http://jsfiddle.net/xGQtF/5/ The css I used is inline so I could get it done quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-size: 100%`  should do the trick.

Here, http://jsfiddle.net/xGQtF/6/

Comment: But it seems only have half the screen.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I got you wrong. What I thought you meant was that the image should be contained within the `pageHead` div in height but occupy the full width of the page. Isn't that so?

Comment: Yes, but occupy the full width of the page

Comment: It does occupy the full width of the page. It is stretched.

Answer (score 0):

If its a gradient or pattern that can be repeated you can use

```
background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

or just insert 'repeat-x' into your background css like

```
background:url(images/blah.jpeg) repeat-x;
```

That way you only need a small chunk of the image>smaller image sizes>quicker loading time.

to get rid of the color it is showing with the image you can use

```
background-color:transparent;
```

Also if, as I suspect, you wish to make the banner stretch seamlessly from one side to the other, be sure to set the body style with

```
padding:0px;
width:100%;
```

and use

```
margin:0px;
width:100%;
```

on the div containing the background.

Although it may stretch to the full width without setting the body padding to 0px, some browsers automatically give the body padding if it isn't set so it will counteract those that do.

If you're using an image that has curved edges and vertices etc this won't be right for you, you just want to stretch it (which personally I think wont look nice on 99% of detailed images) you can use:

```
background-size:100%;
```

Hope I've helped =)